# What are the ways one can get products to show up in a certain order on website without changing SKU numbers?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

Example:
Product A:  SKU# 15
Product B:  SKU# 18

Now on the front end of our website, Product A would show up first because the SKU number is lower than Product B.

Is there any way to get Product B to show up first without making its SKU number lower than Product A's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Catalog -> Categories -> Manage Categories`.

Under the *Display Settings* tab, select the *Default Product Listing Sort By* to "Best Value".

Under the *Category Products* tab, set the position of your products.

Save your category and re-index.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your products within "Manage Categories". Our site is sorted by low price to high and then by name.